# Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-14},\sqrt{-2\sqrt{2}-1})$ has degree 8 over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

We know that the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1}$) over $\mathbb{Q}$ has degree 4 by considering the minimal polynomial mod 3. Now I want to show that $-14$  isn't a square in this field. How do I do this in the easiest way? Please also let me know if you have a method not in this way (e.g. by considering intermediate field extensions in different orders).

Somehow feels like it ought to be true because $-14$ has a factor $7$ in it whereas $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1}$) involves only $2$'s.

If it helps, I found that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-14},\sqrt{-2\sqrt{2}-1})$ is the splitting field of $X^4+2X^2-7$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to see this. The easiest is to realise that $K= \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2\sqrt2-1})\subset \mathbb R$, so it cannot possibly contain a root of $-14$.

Alternatively, you could show that $K$ is not a Galois extension, so it cannot be the splitting field of an (irreducible) polynomial.

Comment: ahhhhh...how could I have been so dumb! But I'm slightly uncomfortable with you saying that K is inside R. I guess you mean that if we took an embedding of K into R (which exists and must fix Q and so -14) then we would get a contradiction, right?

Comment: Usually, when you write $K$ in that form you are picking an embedding. The ambiguity occurs precisely because the extension is not Galois - in a Galois extension, all embeddings have the same image in $\mathbb C$, since an embedding restricts to an automorphism of $K$. Either way, all the embeddings are isomorphic as abstract fields, so if a polynomial has a root in one, it will have a root in all of them.

Comment: btw I tried to edit your answer to be "so it cannot be the splitting field of a polynomial". The "irreducible" isn't important here right? But my edit has been rebuked.

Comment: I think irreducibility matters just so that you know you've picked the right polynomial, but I agree it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Feel free to chat with me [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/38431/mathmos?tab=access).

Answer (score 1):

The splitting field of $X^4+2x^2-7$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is what you have found. This polynomial is separable, hence the extension is Galois.Furthermore,this polynomial is irreducible. I used corollary 4.5 of this wonderful lecture by Keith Conrad : http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf

We can see, by what it says, that $-7 \neq 0$ and $(2^2+4*7)(-7) = -224 \neq 0$, hence the Galois group is $D_4$, wherein the extension is $8$.

For proofs of the facts, you can look at the same paper.